# Expr-esso Store - shipping

Tags: expresso-store

Currently my store installation requires you to press the button 'update cart' to calculate the shipping when at the start of checkout. I don't need anything fancy with the shipping - it just calculates it based on total amount in the basket. Can I get it so that the shipping is automatically calculated when arriving at checkout instead of forcing the user to update the cart?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `{exp:store:cart}` tag or the `{exp:store:checkout}` tag? Basically the Cart Tag behaves exactly the same as the Checkout Tag. The difference lies in performance - while the Checkout Tag provides a form, and provides options for updating and submitting the cart, the Cart Tag simply displays a cached version of the current cart.

Give the `{exp:store:checkout}` tag a try and this should calculate things automatically for you without needing to update the cart:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
    ...
    {order_shipping}
    ...
{/exp:store:checkout}
```